# Cannot select image to make it smaller on small screen devices

Tags: html, css

I have 6 images, and I need them to be smaller on small screens. But I cannot make them smaller using media queries.
I think it has to do with selection.

Here is my current code:

```css
/* on large screens */
.devices {
    height: 5.5em;
    width: 11.5em;
    margin: 0 1em;
}

/* Here is the problem, this code doesn't work */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .devices {
        height: 4.5em;
        width: 9.5em;
    }
}
```

```html
<section>
        <div class="container" id="applied-padding">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h2 id="h2-compatible">Paisjet e mbeshtutura Online TV</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8" id="compatible-with">
                    <img src="images/on-android-min.png" class="devices" alt="android">
                    <img src="images/on-android-min.png" class="devices" alt="android">
                    <img src="images/on-android-min.png" class="devices" alt="android">
                    <img src="images/on-android-min.png" class="devices" alt="android">
                    <img src="images/on-android-min.png" class="devices" alt="android">
                    <img src="images/on-android-min.png" class="devices" alt="android">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

}
```